# How to make Jenkins Pipeline node block pick the same node as last time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got a simple example:

```
node {
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

Running on my local Jenkins it seems that each time I run this pipeline the node block picks a different node. Almost looks like this is done by purpose. I ran the job 5 times, it would **always pick a different node**.

Knowing Freestyle jobs I would have expected that the node block tries to reuse the very node used in the last run so it would save time and resources. But it won't.

I didn't find anything so far about that in the Jenkins documentation. Maybe somebody got a clue or a hidden switch - or at least can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible bug in Jenkins, see: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52529

I've opened a PR, in case you don't want to wait until it's integrated you may do a custom build of my PR:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin/pull/72

For ourselfes at least we'll switch to this very version until it's officially included in Jenkins.